# App Engine application should not create new instances of 'java.lang.Thread'

Tags: google-app-engine

When I use threading in my Google App Engine (GAE) app, the following warning shows up in IntelliJ:

> App Engine application should not create new instances of 'java.lang.Thread'

My app is set to using Java 8. What is strange is that if I load the samples from Google's site, this warning does not show up in IntelliJ. So what is different? The code to creating a thread in my app looks like this:

```
new Thread(new StoreAccountWorker(startSignal, doneSignal)).start();
```

while the sample code from Google looks like this:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        // Use stderr here since the logger may have been reset by its JVM shutdown hook.
        System.err.println("*** shutting down gRPC server since JVM is shutting down");
        HelloWorldServer.this.stop();
        System.err.println("*** server shut down");
      }
    });
```

Oddly, if I paste the Google sample code into my app, the warning does not show up on the `new Thread` of Google's code but it does show up on my line of code.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be an issue with IntelliJ. I'm running IntelliJ 2016.2.4 which does not appear to recognize App Engine's support for threads in Java 8. To turn this warning off, go to IntelliJ's Preferences and under:

> Editor > Code Style > Inspections

scroll down and disable "Google App Engine".